# Trimming multiple columns in a file with perl

Tags: perl, variables, multiple-columns, trim

I am trying to trim out this particular file and need just the highlighted portion as it contains the data. I have looked at some other scripts but they are written to remove columns of constant value.

The data is:

```
id=69 rna=**5_8S_rRNA** ntax=61
id=58 rna=**U1** ntax=100
id=56 rna=**U2** ntax=211
id=37 rna=**tRNA** ntax=967
id=75 rna=**Vault** ntax=75
id=53 rna=**RNaseP_nuc** ntax=117
id=57 rna=**RNaseP_bact_a** ntax=306
id=62 rna=**RNaseP_bact_b** ntax=114
id=41 rna=**U3** ntax=26
id=50 rna=**6S** ntax=154
id=84 rna=**DsrA** ntax=5
id=48 rna=**U4** ntax=178
id=46 rna=**SRP_euk_arch** ntax=102
id=46 rna=**U5** ntax=181
id=65 rna=**GcvB** ntax=26
id=71 rna=**Telomerase-vert** ntax=37
id=50 rna=**Telomerase-cil** ntax=20
id=49 rna=**U6** ntax=200
id=43 rna=**Intron_gpI** ntax=30
id=51 rna=**RNase_MRP** ntax=67
id=33 rna=**SECIS** ntax=61
id=90 rna=**Histone3** ntax=64
id=86 rna=**OxyS** ntax=5
id=98 rna=**RRE** ntax=65
id=54 rna=**IRE** ntax=39
id=73 rna=**rne5** ntax=6
id=88 rna=**snoR9** ntax=5
id=91 rna=**GlmZ_SraJ** ntax=21
id=77 rna=**HDV_ribozyme** ntax=33
id=72 rna=**U8** ntax=49
id=87 rna=**7SK** ntax=45
id=78 rna=**VA** ntax=54
id=79 rna=**RNAI** ntax=10
id=98 rna=**FinP** ntax=6
id=82 rna=**Vimentin3** ntax=19
id=74 rna=**S15** ntax=79
```

I simply wish to keep the items in asterisks, everything else has to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is on a Linux system, this Perl one-liner will produce the result you require.

```
perl -ne '/rna=(\S+)/ and print "$1\n"' myfile
```

If you are on Windows, use

```
perl -ne "/rna=(\S+)/ and print qq($1\n)" myfile
```

**output**

```
5_8S_rRNA
U1
U2
tRNA
Vault
RNaseP_nuc
RNaseP_bact_a
RNaseP_bact_b
U3
6S
DsrA
U4
SRP_euk_arch
U5
GcvB
Telomerase-vert
Telomerase-cil
U6
Intron_gpI
RNase_MRP
SECIS
Histone3
OxyS
RRE
IRE
rne5
snoR9
GlmZ_SraJ
HDV_ribozyme
U8
7SK
VA
RNAI
FinP
Vimentin3
S15
```

Comment: You can leave off the quote around $1, which are only there to interpolate the \n. The `-l` switch will add the newline for you. Or, with the `-E` instead of `-e`, you can use `say` instead of `print`, but that requires v5.10 or later. :)